# TikZ - spath not flipping properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use the library "spath" by Andrew Stacey to concatenate a few paths and fill it inside, and I met the following problem: On the code below I would expect the graphics to flip around the x-axis when the comments are removed - but id does not.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usepackage{spath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [save path=\Middle, xshift=25] svg {M201.1,673.2c1.4-39.8,2-52.2,18.2-70.8c11.7-13.5,18.3-24.3-7.7-49.4
        c-39.3-38-43.2-59.2,1-90.2c18.1-12.7,67.1-20.2,25.4-36.6c-18.2-7.2-23.5-9.7-26.9-39.2c-3-26.7-17.7-28.2-37.7-35
        c-20-6.9-87.7-28.8-50.2-78.2c23.5-31,58.6-73.9,83.1-118.2c13.3-24,22.4-56.5,38.6-85.9};
\path [save path=\Right] svg {M295,69.4c-5.1,25.7-13.3,57.3-19.2,76.5
        c-15,48.3-21.9,52.2-36.7,86.5c-21.5,49.9-47.2,77.8-1.1,90.5c46.7,12.8,49.7,16,48.9,40.6c-0.6,18.4-3.9,35.1,10.3,34.3
        c15.7-0.9,40.5,6,71.5,36.8c8.2,8.1,25,18.7,25,18.7s-159.2,8.6-116.4,73.2c29.6,44.7,31.9,44.4,19.9,66.7
        c-15.1,28.3-28.8,48.8-23,80.6};

\pgfoonew \patha=new spath(\Middle)
\pgfoonew \pathb=new spath(\Right)
\patha.concatenate with lineto(,\pathb)
\patha.close()

%\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]
  \patha.use path with tikz(line width=3pt,draw=black,fill=black)
%\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `transform canvas={yscale=-1}`.

Comment: @Symbol1, where exactly this command goes?

Comment: I guess `\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={yscale=-1}]`

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Still strange why the original file works with simple path, but not with complex ones.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it refers to an obsolete package that is no longer maintained and which has been replaced by a newer one.